# Running 'ng e2e' doesn't output anything to the console

Tags: angular-cli, angular-e2e

When I run `ng e2e` in my angular 7 project root, it doesn't start the dev server and just quits after about 9-10 seconds.

I've tried to create a new project and compare the package.json and angular.json. All the angular dependencies are the same version and angular.json serve, build and e2e commands are also the same.

After running the `ng e2e` command in the newly created project, the output in the console was the same as running `ng serve` and then all the tests ran. In my project, there's no output from this commands.

Thank you for your help

**EDIT**
I am using Angluar 7.2.3 and CLI 7.3.0

Comment: I have had the same issue with Angular version 7.0.2 and cli version 7.0.4. After updating to Angular 7.2.5 and cli 7.3.2, `ng e2e` was working again. Unfortunately I haven't had time to investigate more, but maybe this can serve as a starting point for a full answer. @user7391037 It could help to narrow down the problem if you also provide the exact versions of Angular and ng cli that you are using.